# How to Print Region content on Drupal Panel Layout

Tags: php, drupal-6

I'm using Panels module to create couple of Landing Pages. thos pages are looks more simillar to my page.tpl.php' layout. I want to create the pages using panels and add contents to ragions. and then print those regions on specific locations. the thing is that all panels contents are printed when i print the $content only. but what should i need is i want to acces each diferent regions I defined in panel page and print those in any other place.

i.e say that ive created regions 'left', 'right'.
i want to access those on page.tpl file like $content['left'], $content['right'] like this way.

how can i do this. please assist me . im really great full you all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but it seems that you could use Panels with Views in order to filter your content according to the location of your pages.

Typically , you organize your layout with Panels and define arguments within Views which will handle the various queries and return the appropriate results.